# cURL Post Data Not Sending

Tags: php, curl, laravel

I am trying to send POST data via cURL however it is not sending the data, however when I send them as GET variables it is sending, does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => "local.new.api.test.com/authenticate/"
)); 

$data = array(
    'username'  =>  'test',
    'password'          =>  'test'
);  

$data_string = json_encode($data);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);                                                                   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Is it the full code? Where is URL of request?

Comment: @hindmost Hi, I didn't post it as I was using a local virtual host, I have edited the original post

Comment: Just figured it out.

My virtual host was redirecting the request therefore I had to set the following options to make it forward the post data:

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);

Answer (score 1):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is not a json encoded string. It requires a query string (similar to the query string in the URL-s after the question mark).

This should work:

```
$data_string = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
```

Or you can let the cURL extension to do the dirty work and pass an array with key-value pairs as the value:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

From [PHP.net](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

*This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.*